# not exist in a attribute

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I do a sql query that checks if a row is present ... if there is the tuple I do INSERT INTO Setting else UPDATE. UserID is the primary key. I wanted to try to do it directly in a single query in php ... is it possible? I can somehow use the command not exist?

```
enter code here

$query = 'INSERT INTO Settings SET
             userID = '.$uid.',
      visibility = -1,
      notify_icon = true,
      notify_connect_friend = true,
      notify_near_friend = true,
      ringer = true,
      vibration = true
  ';
$query = 'UPDATE Settings SET
      visibility = '.$visibility.',
      notify_icon = '.$notify_icon.',
      notify_connect_friend = '.$notify_connect_friend.',
      notify_near_friend = '.$notify_near_friend.',
      ringer = '.$ringer.',
      vibration = '.$vibration.'
   WHERE
      userID = '.$uid.'
  ';
```

Comment: Have you considered MySQL replace (not ANSI standard) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way with a single query. Take a look at [On duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `REPLACE` mysql statement.